# How to plot Excel - Gantt Chart with multiple series?

Tags: excel, charts, bar-chart, gantt-chart

Is it possible to plot chart like this using the available dataset ?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnJ6n.jpg

[image: Sample Chart for Reference]
Sample data set for testing

```
Company,Product,StartDate,EndDate,Duration (Days)
C1,P1,01/05/2014 11:21,01/05/2014 16:56,0.23
C1,P2,01/05/2014 17:13,01/05/2014 22:07,0.20
C1,P3,02/05/2014 15:04,02/05/2014 19:56,0.20
C1,P4,03/05/2014 09:01,03/05/2014 14:22,0.22
C1,P5,04/05/2014 00:09,04/05/2014 00:11,0.00
C1,P6,04/05/2014 00:11,04/05/2014 09:00,0.37
C2,P7,04/05/2014 18:53,05/05/2014 00:03,0.22
C2,P8,05/05/2014 01:39,05/05/2014 10:35,0.37
C2,P9,05/05/2014 10:38,05/05/2014 17:53,0.30
C2,P10,05/05/2014 17:55,06/05/2014 05:35,0.49
```

Potentially, I might need to change the Duration so that the bar can be pushed out.

Hope some Excel Charting expert can give me some suggestions whether it is do-able and how I should redesign my data set to produce such charts.

Thanks ...

Comment: It's certainly possible... whether its feasible depends on how you want to implement it. Are you proficient in VBA? If so I may be able to point you in the right direction so you can write your own but a full code solution is probably out of the scope of a SO Answer. If not you should consider moving this post to SuperUser

Comment: I can code VBA but for this chart, I am just exploring the possibility and then produce the data set via SQLServer store procedure and then return the data set to Excel for charting purpose. I believe that it depends on how I organize the data and what to include in the Chart - Select Data, X and Y axis only. That's the part I am missing.

Comment: I tried changing the X and Y axis but can't get the correct combination.

Comment: pnuts, i tried multiple ways to plot it but can't get it right.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, I stumbled across this searching a similar query of my own.  Hope this helps.

I followed the steps here: [Step-by-Step Instructions for Making a Gantt Chart in Excel](https://www.smartsheet.com/blog/gantt-chart-excel01) using the columns "StartDate" and "Duration" for the data, "Company" for the axis label and "Product" for the data labels.

The instructions here: [Easier Gantt Chart for Repeated Tasks](http://peltiertech.com/easier-gantt-chart-for-repeated-tasks/) talked about adding a new data series that had no text for the axis.  Instead I just replaced "C1" and "C2" with "1" and "2" in the table, then set the axis to "date" as instructed.

The sheet I have created is here: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AuDTIKz6HRuPiG7lfc3N5LkTFQFs